# Are both [inequality] and [income-inequality] tags necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [excerpt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) for [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) reads:

> Questions on economic, social, racial, gender and any other forms of political inequality, or political topics related to such inequalities.

While the [excerpt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) for [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) reads:

> Use for questions related to income-inequality and its causes, political effects, or potential solutions.

It appears to me that the "income inequality" of [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) may be no different than the "economic inequality" of [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality).

- [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) has 31 questions
- [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) has 24 questions
- Four questions use both tags
- Some questions with [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) and not [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) are about income (or wealth).

If there were a *finer* line to distinguish between the two tags, there are enough questions of each to keep separate tags; otherwise [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) could be made a synonym of [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality).

Are both [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) and [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) necessary or should they be merged? (Please include any suggestions for amending the tag excerpts, if separate tags are to be maintained.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) should be merged into [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality). If someone wishes to specify that the type of inequality relates to wages then they can include the [income](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income) tag as well. Before merging I suggest we go through the [income-inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-inequality) questions to see if the [income](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income) tag should be added.

That combination of [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) and [income](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income) already happened a few times: [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/what-does-inequality-look-like-when-measured-in-man-hours-employed) and [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/why-is-the-gender-pay-gap-so-large-in-the-united-states-despite-the-equal-pay-ac).

Comment: A review of both [inequality] and [income-inequality] tags is necessary. The [oldest question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/84/26455) for [inequality] is about "income inequality" and not tagged [income].

Comment: I have completed my review of [income-inequality]. I'll interleave my review of [inequality]  with other tags I'm reviewing (over 200 questions).

Comment: @RickSmith nice, I'll do the tag merge in a bit. As for [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/57868), shouldn't the [income] tag be added there?

Comment: I saw the question to be more about [taxes]; but I see that perhaps [income] would be fine. I changed the tags.

Comment: We need to create tag [tag:wealth] in addition to the existing tag [tag:income], to properly tag [tag:income] [tag:inequality] and [tag:wealth] [tag:inequality]. These are related but different, and this difference may be salient sometimes.

Comment: @TimurShtatland - I have asked about creating a [wealth] tag. See: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6109/26455