# Should a [wealth] tag be created?

Tags: discussion, tags

A [comment](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6097/are-both-inequality-and-income-inequality-tags-necessary?cb=1#comment14500_6098) on an answer to the question: [Are both [inequality] and [income-inequality] tags necessary?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6098/26455) suggests the need for a [wealth](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) tag.

> We need to create tag [wealth](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) in addition to the existing tag [income](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income), to properly tag [income](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income) [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) and [wealth](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality). These are related but different, and this difference may be salient sometimes.

While there are only a few [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) questions that could use a [wealth](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) tag, there are [104 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wealth+is%3Aq) mentioning "wealth"; of which, [22 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22wealth%22) use "wealth" in the title. Of course, not all these questions could reasonably use a [wealth](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) tag, but some could.

Many of these questions are about wealth (re-)distribution, taxation, and "gaps" or disparity. Some ask about the personal wealth of politicians as distinct from income.

Specifically, there are [67 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wealth+is%3Aq+-%5Binequality%5D+-income) that mention "wealth", do not mention "income" and are not tagged [inequality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality).

Should a [wealth](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wealth) tag be created? And, if so, what should the excerpt (tag info) say?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that it would be a useful tag, because its not clear what it actually means. It can refer to:

- Wealth disparity and government policies which affect it (like "wealth tax" which could probably need an own tag)
- The wealth of individual politicians
- Sovereign wealth
- The "wealth of a nation" and how it's generated, as coined by Adam Smith

Sure, we *could* decide on one of these and write a tag excerpt that says that if you use it for one of the other purposes you are doing it wrong. But in my experience, instructions in tag excerpts get frequently ignored. With a good tag you should know exactly what you are going to get when you click on it.